# HyperLedger fabric error on bringing up network

Tags: installation, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I am new to HyperLedger and trying to build the first network using the tutorial on https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html.

However, when I run ./byfn.sh up within faric-samples/first-network I get the following error:

[image]

Does anyone know how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check if the vendoring of golang dependencies worked without error. Look for `Vendoring Go dependencies ...` and `Finished vendoring Go dependencies` in the log output of byfn.sh.
Background: for fabric 2.0, the shim package needs to be vendored but seems to be missing.
[byfn.sh should do that](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/master/first-network/byfn.sh#L177), but it might have failed.